# Clion コンソールでの日本語の文字化け

Tags: windows, c, intellij-idea, 文字化け, shift-jis

Clion 2019.1.4 でCプロジェクトを作成し、次のプログラムを実行したところ実行結果の日本語の部分が文字化けしてしまい困っています。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
printf("ハローワールド");
return 0;
}
```

実行結果

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.exe
繝上Ο繝ｼ繝ｯ繝ｼ繝ｫ繝
Process finished with exit code 0
```

ソースファイルのエンコードはUTF-8です。
ためしにソースファイルのエンコードをShiftJISに変更してみたら直りましたが、できればソースファイルのエンコードはUTF-8のままで文字化けを改善したいと思っております。

その他、試したことは以下の通りです。

- Custom VM Optionの末尾に-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8の追加。
- 設定のEditor/Font, Editor/Color Scheme/Color Scheme Font, Editor/Color Scheme/Console FontのフォントをSource Han Code JP Lへの変更

OSはWindows 10 Home Version 1803 Build 17134.829 です。

おそらくソースファイルがUTF-8でコンソールのエンコードがShift JISになっているため文字化けしていると思われるのですが、確証がもてませんし、どう対処したらいいのかわかりません。

どうしたら文字化けが直るのでしょうか。

追記
実行ではなくデバッグをすると文字化けせずに表示されました。
実行のコンソールとデバッグのコンソールとではエンコードが異なるのでしょうか。
できれば実行のコンソール上でも文字化けがないようにしたいです。

Comment: 確認なのですが、console.encoding=UTF-8` を指定後 Clionの再起動は行いましたか？

Comment: はい、設定後にClionの再起動を行いました。

Comment: Windowsならまずは標準環境としてVisual Studio及びShift-JISを使うことをおすすめします。それができてから順にステップアップしていった方が原因の切り分けも容易です。例えばソースコードをUTF-8にしたいということですが、コンパイル生成された実行ファイル内の文字列についてはUTF-8 / Shift-JISの希望はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 大学の課題を行ったりするのに、大学での実行環境がLinuxなのでソースファイルがUTF-8でないと文字化けしてしまい、提出の時にかなり面倒なんです。コンパイル生成後の実行ファイル内の文字列については何でもいいです。
Clionを使う理由は前にjavaを使ってた時にIntellj ideaを使っていたので、同じJetbrains製品を使いたいなと思ったためです。

Answer (score 0):

入力と出力でキャラクタセットが異なるため、明示的に指定する必要があります。
MakeLists.txtに以下の行を追加してみてください。

> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /execution-charset:SHIFT_JIS /source-charset:UTF-8")

Comment: CMakeLists.txtに追加し、実行してみましたが依然として文字化けしたままでした。ですがRunではなくDebugをしてみたところ、CMakeLists.txtのキャラクタセットの指定の有無にかかわらず文字化けはしませんでした。